# Covariance of two Monte Carlo estimations

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, covariance

Suppose that we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ s.t. for every value of $\left\{i\in\mathbb{Z}:1\leq i\leq n\right\}$, there exists a tuple $\left(X_{i},Y_{i}\right)$.

Let the Monte Carlo estimation for the $\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]$ be $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ respectively, i.e.
$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$$
$$\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}$$

How do I express $\operatorname{cov}\left(\bar{X},\bar{Y}\right)$ in terms of $\operatorname{cov}\left(X,Y\right)$? Are they equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $X_i$ are iid. Likewise for $Y_i$. Then,
$$
\eqalign{
\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X},\bar{Y})&=\mathbb{E}\left[\bar{X}\bar{Y}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\bar{X}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\bar{Y}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\right]
-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}Y_{i}\,+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\ne j}X_{i}Y_{j}\right]
-\frac{n}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\,\frac{n}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]\\
&=\frac{n}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right]+\frac{n^2-n}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]
-\frac{n}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\,\frac{n}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right]-\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)
}
$$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_i Y_i]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i Y_j]$, $i\neq j$ should both be $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ because they are both defined over the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. But you have $\mathbb{E}[X_i Y_i] = \mathbb{E}[XY]$ whereas $\mathbb{E}[X_i Y_j] = \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$, where you have assumed that $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are uncorrelated when $i \neq j$.

Comment: My first line states a common assumption, from which it follows that $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent if $i\ne j$. Perhaps the person who asked the question can clarify.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your stated assumption is that $X_i$'s are iid and $Y_i$'s are also iid. It does not follow from this that $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are correlated if $i=j$ and uncorrelated otherwise.

Comment: Okay, fine. There is an additional assumption that the tuples are independent draws distributed according to the joint pdf f(x,y).